# How to sideload apps to Windows 8.1 tablet from command line

Tags: command-line, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, tablet, sideloading

I am new to Windows 8.1 app development. I have registered my Windows phone using "Windows Phone Registration" tool and was able to successfully deploy a "Hello, World" app onto it both from Visual Studio as well as from the command line.

This [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022911/registering-windows-tablet-8-1-for-development-of-windows-store-apps) says that development for Windows phones is not same as that of for tablets. We have to install remote debugger tools on the tablet and tell Visual Studio that we want to debug it on remote machine.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any other way to deploy apps during development other than installing remote debugger tools on the tablet?
2. How can I sideload apps from command line onto the tablet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create an appx package for the app not intended for upload to the Store (Visual Studio -> Project -> Store -> Create App Packages -> "No")

2) Zip up the AppX folder and transfer it to the tablet, unzip on tablet

3) Right-click "Add-AooDevPackage.psd1", run as administrator

This will install the package to your tablet.  You can create a command-line app which will run this command as well.